# How to autostart notebook on electric power is connected?

Tags: laptop, battery, power

Have a arcade machine and a hp elitebook (8440p). How to start notebook automaticaly when plug the energy?, I want to avoid soldering the part of the power button to have an external button, I prefer that it starts when it is connected to the electric power. It's possible?, Some configuration of the bios or some bridge that I should create? Underneath it has workstation connectors. I use Linux and lakka tv.

On BIOS pc the option exists: "power-on when AC power is restored" but in elitebook is not found, the bios is very restricted. In youtube channels says use the jumper on the motherboard, but for desktop. I'm looking for the jumpers on elitebook motherboard.

Comment: Notebooks are designed to not do that as it would be quite inconvenient for everybody else.

Comment: “Have a arcade machine and a hp elitebook…” What does that arcade machine have to do with anything?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 As "Lakka" is a games emulator it would appear that the "arcade machine" is actually powered by the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

The option in the PC BIOS is when power is restored after a power outage.
There wouldn't be a power outage in a laptop unless the battery completely runs out (unlikely) or the battery is removed such that the charger is the only power source.

Removing the battery and flashing the BIOS with a custom firmware that has this feature would be required.

**Note flashing the BIOS is risky and could result in bricking the motherboard.
This could make the laptop unusable and require a replacement motherboard.**

Answer (score 1):

The “Power on when AC power is restored” won’t suit your purpose. This is for restoration of power after a power loss. If you shutdown the netbook, then you have to start it normally.

There is an option in BIOS (I searched in my netbook but has not found the option) for Power on with USB keyboard and other one is power on when AC is connected.

You need the second option. But since there is no option on your elitebook, you might add a custom bios but I wouldn’t recommend that. As CausingUnderflowseverywhere said, it could brick motherboard.

The best option which I also used is mapping the power button and soldering an external button if you can open the netbook.

In my case, the power button was linked to the keyboard itself, and my power button was linked to the 3rd pin in the keyboard ribbon connector. I added wires to the 3rd pin and the ground and made a custom power button. Geniuses in YouTube may have already mapped the power button like in my case.

I can’t comment because I don't have 50 reputations. So I added it as an answer.

Comment: Right on! Comments aren't meant to have answers in the first place, they are recommended to be used to request additional information or for suggesting improvements. Welcome to Super User!

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this, but I postilate a solution in the form of "a bridge you can make"

It appears your HP supports wake-on-lan.  Enable this and get a trivial pc - an arduino or similar would be ideal - and power it from the same power source. Configure it to send Wake On LAN requests to your laptop whenever it is powered on.